# Python defaultdict - add another key?

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I'm probably not using the right words here, but basically I want to add another key next to the first key that's provided.

This is what I currently have:

```
def transform_result(self, data):
    type_map = defaultdict(list)
    for entry in data:
        type_map[entry['type']].append({
            'id': entry['id'],
            'tag': entry['tag'],
        })
    ret = []
    for key, value, in type_map.items():
        ret.append({
            'type': key,
            'tags': value,
        })
    return ret
```

Input:

```
[
    OrderedDict([
        ('id', 1),
        ('type', 'Color'),
        ('writable', True),
        ('tag', 'Blue')
    ]),
    OrderedDict([
        ('id', 2),
        ('type', 'Color'),
        ('writable', True),
        ('tag', 'Red')
    ]),
    OrderedDict([
        ('id', 3),
        ('type', 'Color'),
        ('writable', True),
        ('tag', 'Green')
    ]),
    OrderedDict([
        ('id', 4),
        ('type', 'Shape'),
        ('writable', False),
        ('tag', 'Square')
    ]),
    OrderedDict([
        ('id', 5),
        ('type', 'Shape'),
        ('writable', False),
        ('tag', 'Circle')
    ])
]
```

Desired output:

```
[
    {
        'type': 'Color',
        'writable': True,
        'tags': [
            {
                'tag': 'Blue',
                'id': 1
            },
            {
                'tag': 'Red',
                'id': 2
            },
            {
                'tag': 'Green',
                'id': 3
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'type': 'Shape',
        'writable': False,
        'tags': [
            {
                'tag': 'Square',
                'id': 4
            },
            {
                'tag': 'Circle',
                'id': 5
            },

        ]
    },
]
```

How should this be accomplished?

---

Edit: I got it, sorry I totally rubber ducked this. Here's my hacky solution:

```
def transform_result(self, data):
    type_map = defaultdict(list)
    for entry in data:
        type_map[entry['type'], entry['many']].append({
            'id': entry['id'],
            'tag': entry['tag'],
        })
    ret = []
    for key, value, in type_map.items():
        ret.append({
            'type': key[0],
            'many': key[1],
            'tags': value
        })
    return ret
```

Basically, the thing that was confusing me was how to access the `many` after the  first loop had completed. My solution was to quickly put the `type` and `many` together in a little list, then access them with `[0]` and `[1]`, it works!

Comment: can you please provide a clearer description of your goal instead of an [XYproblem](http://xyproblem.info/)? input and output, an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `defaultdict` is built around adding a value for a single missing key; if you want something else, you might as well start from `class MyThing(dict)`.

Comment: The `writable` key doesn't need to be checked for existence, it just needs to be appended on the same level as the key itself.

Comment: What happens for non-matching `type` and `writable`? Because in the example, a `Color` is always `writable` and `Shape` is always `False`

Comment: That case doesn't exist in the data I'm using, but if it does happen, it should create a new entry.

Comment: If you have an answer for your question, submit it as an answer and accept it. However, take into account that your proposed "solution" is not compatible with your "Input" / "Desired output" (`writable` and `many` are mysterious field names). I feel like you are arriving to my solution, which is in fact very close to you first version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say that I like your data model, but for your given input and desired output, you almost had it:

```
def transform_result(self, data):
    type_map = defaultdict(list)
    for entry in data:
        type_map[entry['type'], entry['writable']].append({
            'id': entry['id'],
            'tag': entry['tag'],
        })
    ret = []
    for (k_type, k_writable), value in type_map.items():
        ret.append({
            'type': k_type,
            'writable': k_writable,
            'tags': value,
        })
    return ret
```

Comment: I prefer your solution, it seems most aligned with what I want to accomplish. I didn't know that variables could be assigned nested like that, pretty neat! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion, note that this solution is n*lg(n), you can solve the problem in n, but if you dont have very big datasets it will not matter. Use it as inspiration ;)

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
from pprint import pprint


foo = [
    OrderedDict([
        ('id', 1),
        ('type', 'Color'),
        ('writable', True),
        ('tag', 'Blue')
    ]),
    ...
    ...
    ...
    OrderedDict([
        ('id', 5),
        ('type', 'Shape'),
        ('writable', False),
        ('tag', 'Circle')
    ])
]


def transform_result(data):
    key_func = itemgetter('type')
    for g, items in groupby(sorted(foo, key=key_func), key=key_func):
        item = {'type': g, 'tags': []}
        for i in items:
            item['writeable'] = i['writable']
            item['tags'].append({'tag': i['tag'], 'id': i['id']})
        yield item

pprint(list(transform_result(foo)))
```

Output

```
[{'tags': [{'id': 1, 'tag': 'Blue'},
           {'id': 2, 'tag': 'Red'},
           {'id': 3, 'tag': 'Green'}],
  'type': 'Color',
  'writeable': True},
 {'tags': [{'id': 4, 'tag': 'Square'}, {'id': 5, 'tag': 'Circle'}],
  'type': 'Shape',
  'writeable': False}]
```

Comment: If the datasets are not very big, using the generator approach seems overkill, don't you think? And instead of updating `item['writeable']` in each iteration you could move that assignment outside the inner loop. If you do it before the `yield` you will have same behaviour, if you move it before the inner loop you will take into account the first element instead of the last one. Note that either of those behaviour are *not* the desired, according the comments (no information available in the original answer).